# can the sdk manager run in the background while running eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have downloaded the Android SDK and stared the SDK Manager, there are alot of API levels where each API level has its different SDK Platform and System Image.

Can I start downloading one of the API levels packages while I am using eclipse with another API package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no problem in that. You just can't start the SDK Manager using the button on Eclipse; you have to start it executing `/path/to/sdk/tools/android`.

Anyway, you will finish donwloading the different SDKs in no time, or you can just download the most relevant one now and let the others download when you go to sleep (or any other moment when you are not using Eclipse). Well, I guess I just can't picture why waiting for the download would be a problem (I'm sure you've got your reasons; this is me thinking aloud).